# How to hang a canvas art using these nails?

Tags: hanging, nails

Just received my canvas wall art, and it came with the following parts:
[image: Weird nails with gears]

I have never in my life seen that kind of wall hanging kit. What are those nails?

1. They seem unnecessarily thick...
2. What are those plastic gears on them for?

Ironically enough, the instructions that came with this, say to use the 3-pin hanger - clearly not what was provided in the package... But since that's what it came with, I figured I might as well use it.

My only question is... **how?** Do I screw the sawtooth thingy to the frame, hammer the nail into the wall at an angle (including the weird plastic gear around it), and then hang the canvas on the... gear??

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Those are nails for a powder-activated driver (Ramset, *et al*) as far as I know. designed to be driven into concrete by a charge of gunpowder. . I'd chalk the mess up to a bad joke or some major staffing problems where this came from.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I would consider this a mistake... but.. I bought 2 separate canvas paintings, and each one came with those. Quick google search does seem to indicate that you may be right though... I feel even more confused now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick to the screws, and buy something appropriate to your wall-type at the hardware store to hang from.

The serrated bits are a form of picture hanger that normally mounts on the wooden frame (top center, usually just one, the serrations allow you to move it on a nail or screw until it hangs straight. If you use more than one, you have to get the things in the wall exactly right for the art to hang straight, as then there's no adjusting that way.)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what's been said here. Go get a separate hanging kit, because those nails do not look like they're meant to hang art. They look like nails that are supposed to be driven into concrete with a .22 blank round.

I'd email the company and request a partial refund or a correct hanging kit.

Answer (score 0):

Screw the tooth hanger to the frame tooth facing downwards. The nails I wouldn't use. There are many nail type hangers on the market but this picture is my go to. It nails easily into sheetrock and if you predrill a slightly smaller hole, you can use it on plaster. You should consider how heavy the artwork is when choosing the method of mounting.

[image]

For heavier items I prefer picture hanging wire and D ring hangers shown below to the saw tooth . This method also allows you to level the picture easily.

[image]